# Mathematical proof and intuitive reasoning for a problem based on unit step and unit impulse functions.

Tags: calculus, limits

> This is basically a communication engineering and signal processing
>   question. However, since this question involves mathematics, I was
>   adviced by the members of Electrical Engineering Stack exchange to
>   post it in this forum. So if anybody is involved in this field and
>   have concepts pertaining to unit step and unit impulse functions, they
>   may solve this problem.

It would be very helpful if someone could provide the intuitive reasoning and mathematical proof for:

$$\lim \limits_{a \to 0} \frac{1}{a}[u(\frac{t}{a}+\frac{1}{2})-u(\frac{t}{a}-\frac{1}{2})]= \delta(t) $$

where,

u(t)=Unit step function.

$\delta(t)$ is the unit impulse function.

Thank you.

Comment: `$\delta$`  $\delta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look  at the two cases:

$t\neq0$:

If $|a| < |t|$ then $|\frac{t}{a}| > 1$ so both $u(\frac{t}{a}+\frac{1}{2})$  and $u(\frac{t}{a}-\frac{1}{2})$ have the same sign.

Because either $\frac{t}{a} < -1$ then we get $\frac{t}{a}+\frac{1}{2} < -1 + 0.5 = -0.5 < 0 $ and $\frac{t}{a}-\frac{1}{2} < -1 - 0.5 = -1.5 < 0 $.
  $\quad$ So both arguments of the unit step function are negative which leads to:
$u(\frac{t}{a}+\frac{1}{2})-u(\frac{t}{a}-\frac{1}{2}) = -1 - (-1) = 0$

or  $\frac{t}{a} > 1$ then we get $\frac{t}{a}+\frac{1}{2} > 1 + 0.5 = 1.5 > 0 $ and $\frac{t}{a}-\frac{1}{2} > 1 - 0.5 = 0.5 > 0 $.
  $\quad$ So both arguments of the unit step function are positive which leads to:
$u(\frac{t}{a}+\frac{1}{2})-u(\frac{t}{a}-\frac{1}{2}) = 1 - 1 = 0$

So $u(\frac{t}{a}+\frac{1}{2}) - u(\frac{t}{a}-\frac{1}{2}) = 0$ which makes the series constant $0$ from that point on and the limit being $0$.

$t=0$

$\frac{1}{a}[u(\frac{0}{a}+\frac{1}{2}) - u(\frac{0}{a}-\frac{1}{2})] =
\frac{1}{a}[1- (-1)] = 2*\frac{1}{a}$

which should be a well known series that diverges to infinity.

Comment: Sir, I have understood your explanation. Could you please elaborate this point a bit more: If $|a| < |t|$ then $|\frac{t}{a}| > 1$ so both $u(\frac{t}{a}+\frac{1}{2})$  and $u(\frac{t}{a}-\frac{1}{2})$ have the same sign.

Comment: Sir, could it mean that when the magnitude of a is so less than t, that it makes t/a very large value(in magnitude), the addition or subtraction of 0.5 makes both $u(\frac{t}{a}$ and $\frac{1}{2})$ fall on the same side (either +ve or -ve) of x axis?

Comment: Yes exactly....

Comment: Sir, then what is the significance of 1/2 here? Can it be any other fraction?

Comment: Yes it would be the same result for every other numbers. We need one positive and one negative number in the second case though.